# How many media service providers are available?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, video-processing

I am building a scalable multi party video conferencing application. I have checked few open source project which we can use for media server on self hosted server. But I would like to know about how many media service providers are available, because this solves the problem of building our own media server and manage the same.

Is there any cloud providers these kind of services?

Comment: “ I would like to know about how many media service providers are available” there are hundreds.

Comment: @szatmary is google, amazon or azure provides this kind of services?

Comment: Yes, all three, and about 1000 more companies as well. And often cheeper and more efficient than those you mentioned.

Comment: @szatmary I didn't find any information on google cloud, could you please share the link which I can refer for media server.